# Why does repaint() cause a different cause different results than resizing the window? (Java)

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to build a program that displays random shapes and random text. This is my code inside my class that extends JPanel.

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) { 
    // draw all shapes        
    super.paintComponent(g);     // clears the background       

    this.add(new JLabel(new RandomText().getRandomSentence()));
    for (RandomShape shape : shapes) {
       shape.draw(g);
    }         
}
```

I use a JPanel instead of g.drawString() to in the future display HTML code. I also have a button that "regenerates" the window, by calling the repaint() method. However, when I push the regenerate button, thus calling the repaint() method, the shapes change (like they're supposed to), the text however does not. What I find even stranger is when I resize the window new labels are continously added to my panel (with random text like they're supposed to).

Does super.paintCompnent(g) not clear components added to the panel? If so, why does calling repaint() myself not add extra labels, like resizing the window does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resizing the window also forces `validate()` to be called which lays out the components on the panel again - simply repainting does not.

However, in your painting method you're adding a new JLabel each time and not removing any, which almost certainly isn't what you want to do. You should keep track of the JLabel in a separate variable and either change it's position when you repaint (preferably) or remove it before adding a new one.

Comment: Ok so if I understand you correctly, the components are still added to the JPanel if I call repaint() myself, but I just can't see them because they're not layed out by the validate() method? And super.paintComponent(g) actually does clear the window including the exrta JLabels, but they're automatically repainted every time JPanel is redrawn, because they've been "permanently" added to the JPanel? (Note: I knew adding the components inside the paintcomponent method was wrong, I was just curious about the behaviour it displayed)

Answer (score 2):

This adds a new label to the panel at every repaint:

```
this.add(new JLabel(new RandomText().getRandomSentence()));
```

Instead, you should add one label *once* to the panel, perhaps in the constructor of your class. Then `setText(aRandomSentence)` for it, when the button is pressed. Do **not** modify components in `paintComponent()`.

Answer (score 2):

when `super.paintComponent(..);` is called it wipes out the graphics elements. It however does not change the objects that have been added to it. You will be adding a new label to the panel every time repaint is called.

When you call repaint(); yourself, it's not guarenteed to call the paintComponent of all components. But when you resize it HAS to since everything is going to be different.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you're constantly adding new JLabels to the JPanel.
Keep track of your JLabel and change it's text instead of adding new JLabels.